# Codeignitier "set_cookie" is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in CodeIgnitier with no luck.
I was searching for a solution, and i found some posts also here on Stackoverflow, but none of them actually solved the problem for me.

The code is:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
set_cookie('username',$this->input->post('username'));
```

No cookie was set after execution.

In order to avoid wrong answers:
'secure' is set to FALSE in config file, everything else is also as default.
According to the browser, no cookie was set. only Codeignitier native cookie - ci_session is listed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it via array like so:

```
$cookie = array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'value' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'expire' => '0', // expiration time 0 is until browser closes, set to large number for 'remember me' cookie
    'domain' => '.mysite.com', // set this to the domain the cookie will be under with a leading .
    'path' => '/',
    'prefix' => '',
    'secure' => FALSE
); 
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i was trying every way, including $this->input->set_cookie, with array or without array. nothing works. By the way, helpers can never extends a class, but it's true that the function is an alias of $this->input->set_cookie function

Comment: It must be with a value, since the login works. I set the cookie when a user log in, in order to be able to "remember" his username for later access

Comment: I stand corrected about the extending. I just checked the source, and it indeed is an alias. =o)

Comment: Honestly it's my first time using cookie at all, so if you can extend your answer please